# min value(greater than 0) from column combined with row operation

Tags: r

I am trying to get the minimum value (greater than 0) from a column in a matrix and then use the row number where that minimum occurred to calculate a value that gets applied (as a formula) to all rows below the minimum row(identified previously).

Let me demonstrate with an example:
If I define x as:

```
x<-rbind(c(0, 0, 0), c(0,0,3), c(0,3,5))
```

such that `x` is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    3
[3,]    0    3    5
```

then I would like to identify that column 1 has no minimum, column 2 has a minimum at index 3, and column 3 has an minimum at index 2.

So, I created the following attempt at creating a vector of minimums:

```
min<-apply(x,2,function (v) min(which(v>0), na.rm = TRUE))
```

This gives me a warning:

```
Warning message:
In min(which(v > 0), na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

(problem 1): Which I do not know how to avoid.

(problem 2):
I now need to take the results of the minimum (where one exists) and calculate the value of a function based on the value of the vector min, as well as using the index of the vector min to select a value from a different matrix `st`  This I have played around a bit with, without resorting to loops, am unsure of how to do.

Going back to the example, the first value in `min` is `Inf`, so my vector `calc.results` gets 0, the next value in `min` is 3, so from matrix `st` I would like to select the 3rd row in the 2nd column (3) and then use this value to calculate the result for the 2nd column in `calc.results`, etc.  After the operation is complete `calc.results` would look something like (for example simplicity, nothing is done with the value from `st`):

```
[1] 0 3 3
```

I then need to apply `calc.results` back to matrix `st` by subtracting the value of `calc.results` only after I have reached the row identified earlier in `min` (with the index of `min` equaling the column of `st`) All other rows are left untouched.

In the example, the final result would look something like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2
```

since in the 2nd column, the value of `min` was 3, and the value of `calc.results` was 3 in the 2nd column, `st` has 3 subtracted in 2nd column only in row 3, etc (note that the fact, the columns become zeroed out is a product of this example and not generally true).

Comment: Use `which.min`, .....

Comment: I played around with, but I had trouble getting it to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do something like this:

```
apply(x, 2, function(y) { y[y > 0] <- (y[y > 0] - min(y[y > 0])); y })
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2
```

Comment: yeah. this gives me something to play around with and try to understand. what does the extra x do at the end of function in the apply? (I'm thinking it has something to do with returning the entire row?)

Comment: @user1790121, yes. That just returns the entire value of the anonymous function (which I should have changed to something other than "x" since we are working on an object named "x" too, perhaps causing some confusion).

Comment: It's cool, I understand now.  You just taught me you can do that. Cool!

Comment: I've run into one problem with the solution here.  I need to get a value from a different matrix in my anonymous function (same location), in order to compute the required difference.  In my example, I call the matrix `st`.  Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: my code so far looks like this: `apply(dv, 2, function(y) { y[y>0] <- (y[y>0] - 
                                       blacksch(min(
                                         ifelse(any(y>0), y[y>0], 0)),k,sigma,r,
                                                (min(ifelse(any(y>0), (which(y>0)/steps) *t ,0))))
                                     ); 
                          y })`  The problem is the first parameter of blacksch needs to be the value from a different matrix(but in the same location (row/column) as the minimum from the `dv` matrix.  Maybe this should be a new question?

Comment: @user1790121, it's hard to tell without seeing some sample input and expected output as you did for this question; perhaps this question was too simplified to address your actual problem. Also, can you explain what you're doing with the `ifelse(...` part of your question?

Comment: I'll open a new question and give some more robust sample data.  To answer your question, the `ifelse` is there to remove the warnings when a column has no minimum value greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

problem(1)

the warning is due to the fact that you are taking `min` of a non-number, namely `integer(0)`

```
# try this to see the warning clearly: 
min(integer(0))

# try this to see where you are getting integer(0)
apply(x,2,function (v) which(v>0))
```

To avoid the warning, you can add an if-statement in `function(v)` such as:

```
apply(x, 2, function (v) min(ifelse(any(v>0), which(v>0), 0), na.rm = TRUE))
```

however, keep in mind that it is just a warning, and so long as you are aware of what specifically is causing it, you do not need to worry much about it.

Comment: ah yes. sometimes there are columns with no values > 0, but how do I 'protect' myself from that situation?

Comment: you can put an `if` statement (I edited my answer to reflect).  However, @Ananda Mahto's answer seems pretty spot on

Comment: I agree, but I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

problem(1): You can at least identify the columns without any min, then remove them later as needed.

```
min <- apply(x,2,function (v) ifelse(max(v)==0, NA , min(which(v>0), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: oh cool, so if I set them to NA, then the na.rm = TRUE in the min will actually do something.