# use value from different matrix in apply

Tags: r

This question is a follow up to a previous question: [min value(greater than 0) from column combined with row operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14929693/min-valuegreater-than-0-from-column-combined-with-row-operation/)

Essentially, I need to use the value from a differant matrix (same row/column) to pass in as parameter in the anonomous function of apply.

My code is

```
apply(dv, 2, function(y) { y[y>0] <- (y[y>0] - 
                                       blacksch(min(
                                         ifelse(any(y>0), y[y>0], 0)),k,sigma,r,
                                                (min(ifelse(any(y>0), (which(y>0)/steps) *t ,0))))
                                     ); 
                          y })
```

the `min(
                                             ifelse(any(y>0), y[y>0], 0))` needs to be from a different matrix `st` but in the exact same location (row/column wise) as the value in dv.

As an example I could have the following two matrices dv and st:

```
> dv
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    3
[3,]    0    3    5
> st
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
[1,]  100 100.00 100.00
[2,]  100 100.00 102.95
[3,]  100 102.34 104.88
```

I would need to pass in the value 102.34 for column 2 to the first parameter of the function `blacksch` (since this corresponds to the same position as the smallest value greater than 0 in column 2 of the matrix `dv`

so I know this not correct but something like:

```
apply(dv, 2, function(y) { y[y>0] <- (y[y>0] - 
                                           blacksch(st[minimum position of value greater than 0 in dv for each column],k,sigma,r,
                                                    (min(ifelse(any(y>0), (which(y>0)/steps) *t ,0))))
                                         ); 
                              y })
```

I guess I should also mention that I need not only the minimum value from `st`, but also the 'current' value(if I were to write this in a loop, I would do something similar to nested for loops)

My solution is not really the R way (and thus suffers from horrible performance):

```
for(j in 1:paths)
{
  minrow=0
  for(i in 1:steps)
  {
    if (dv[i,j]>0 && minrow==0)
    {
      minrow=i
      bsminrow=blacksch(st[i,j],k,sigma,r, i/steps * t)
    }
    else if (minrow!=0)
    {
      dv[i,j]=blacksch(st[i,j],k,sigma,r,i/steps* t ) - bsminrow
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of speeding this up (especially if you've got a lot of rows) is to use `sort` with `partial` match option instead of `order` as it obtains all indices > 0 (from @agstudy's answer).

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(dv)), function(x) {
    idx <- ifelse (any(dv[,x] != dv[1,x]), 
            which(dv[,x] == sort(unique(dv[,x]), partial=2)[2]),
            seq_along(dv[,x]))
    st[idx, x]
})

# [[1]]
# [1] 100
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 102.34
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 102.95
```

Basically, for every column, fetch `dv's` 2nd "minimum" index and get corresponding value from `st`. If `0` is always your minimum, then it gives you the exact result as agstudy's. I assume this is the case for you. Because, if the maximum value is 0, which one do you take? (of course these are special cases and I'll leave you to it). This solution works the same way as agstudy's but will be faster if you've more rows (as it performs a `partial sort`).

Since I'm not sure how you want to handle ties (if there are > 1 times the same value > 0), I've given the output as a list. If you're sure there are no ties, you can change `lapply` to `sapply`. If there are ties, then you can, for example, choose just the first element from `lapply` output. I'll leave these special cases to you as well.

Comment: this is great.  I appreciate you leaving some bits out for me to practice with.

Answer (score 1):

You can change you `apply` by `sapply` to loop through columns  for example:

```
sapply(1:ncol(dv), function(y) {       
               h <- st[,y]                ## y is column number     
               y <- dv[,y]                ## y is column now
               st.par <- ifelse(any(y)> 0,
                 h[head(which(y[order(y)] >0),1)], ## I order here to and I choose the first one
                                                   ## > 0
               h[1])
               st.par
               ###.....   here you call your custom function
               ###blacksch(st.par,...)
})

1] 100.00 102.34 102.95
```

Comment: Is that the best from a performance standpoint?  I edited the question to add my horribly 'un-R' solution (using nested loops).

Comment: if performance is a concern, you might want to take a look at data.table.  I was turned onto it via SO and have been absolutely blown away

Comment: data.table interesting, looks a bit like SQL for R